# How can I increase or decrease the quantity of a specific item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a question of understanding. I have different items, for each the user should be able to choose how much he wants. The articles are stored in Firebase with Img, Name, Category. How can the user now increase an item without an update being sent to the DB every time? Only when the user clicks a button should all quantities, in each case, be written to the database. The users are also stored in a DB with key and room.

[image]

Here is my code for the Food Articel:

```
{filter?.map((art, idx) => {
  return <Food key={idx} art={art}></Food>;
})}

....

export default function Food({ art }) {

const [artikel, setArtikel] = useState(art);
const [anzahl, setAnzahl] = useState(0);

const updateAnzahl = (action, artName) => {
if (action === "remove") {
  setArtikel((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [artName]: {
      anzahl: anzahl - 1,
    },
  }));
} else {
  setArtikel((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [artName]: {
      anzahl: anzahl + 1,
    },
  }));
 }
};


  <IconButton
    aria-label="delete"
    onClick={() => updateAnzahl("remove", art.name)}
        >
          <RemoveIcon fontSize="large"></RemoveIcon>
      </IconButton>

        <Typography variant="h5">{anzahl}</Typography>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="delete"
          onClick={() => updateAnzahl("add", art.name)}
        >
          <AddIcon fontSize="large"></AddIcon>
        </IconButton>
```

Comment: place a submit button and when a user submits, send all the new info to Firebase and store everything that has been updated once!

Comment: Then I would need a separate hook state for each article?

Comment: no need for that. just define the `selection` object as a state like `{foo:1, bar:1, ...}` and one hook to update this state object based on the user's selection. then send it to your server after the user submits it.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking to debounce the increment/decrement function, i.e. only after *some* delta from the last time the local value was incremented or decremented is the call made to the backend. Or, as others have suggested, add a "submit" button to do a single update to the backend. Do you need further help from here? If so then we need a better [mcve] that includes the API call(s).

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  StatusBar,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

const items = [
  {
    name: 'item 1',
    qty: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'item 2',
    qty: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'item 3',
    qty: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'item 4',
    qty: 0,
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(items);
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(''); // <- Add if your view not Rerender

  const handleIncrease = (index) => {
    const temp = data;
    temp[index].qty = temp[index].qty + 1;
    setData(temp);
    setRefresh(Math.random()); // <- Add if your view not Rerender
  };

  const handleDecrease = (index) => {
    const temp = data;
    temp[index].qty = temp[index].qty - 1;
    setData(temp);
    setRefresh(Math.random()); // <- Add if your view not Rerender
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 50,
          width: '90%',
          marginLeft: '5%',
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'black',
          marginBottom: 10,
          flexDirection: 'row',
        }}>
        <Text style={{ marginRight: 20 }}>{item.name}</Text>

        <Button title="Increase" onPress={() => handleIncrease(index)} />
        <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }}>{item.qty}</Text>
        <Button title="Decrease" onPress={() => handleDecrease(index)} />
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

snack link: https://snack.expo.dev/9ZsvSkXBk

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep the user's current order in browser's session/local storage and update database on some "submit" button. Piece of cake :-)

BTW. An issue to consider - what if user has more than one tab/browser opened on your app - should any instance simply overwrite others data or you need some syncing between them?

here's link to codesandbox with boilerplate for order management: https://codesandbox.io/s/hotel-cafe-order-f5wp7d

Comment: And how can I then assign the article to the quantity? What if the admin adds a new article, where does the state come from?

Comment: On app initialization I assume you get list of available articles. Then you set up a state for the "cart" which would be an array of objects like [{ articleId: 1, quantity: 3 }, { articleId: 2, quantity: 5 }] Then on each state change you update local storage (to keep the cart in case of user closing the browser).

Comment: Ok, I added my program code above. If I click on Add, the object is added, but removed again as soon as I add another article

Comment: `function Food({ art })` renders single item/Artikel on the list?

Comment: - Yes, exactly.

Comment: ok, I edited my answer by adding link to codesandbox - check if it suits you as a starter (no local storage and no submit button, but quantity changes are implemented)